# Why is my computer is printing in inverted colours suddenly?

Tags: printing, printer, colors

I try printing a regular document in either Word or PDF, looks fine in every view, then when printed, I get a black background with white letters (similarly with color images by the way, the printers are B&W only). Everyone else in the office can print fine, I've gone through every single setting I've found for the printers, the programs, changed colour schemes, let the printers choose colours, etc., still nothing. I have removed and reinstalled the printers, restarted the computer, nothing. Grasping at straws here, but one thing I can think of that might have caused it is the new Windows update (1903, May) applied to my PC. I decided to try the new Dark Mode for the Apps, but after I encountered the issue I set it back to light, restarted the computer, all the app UIs have changed back, but the issue still stands. Can someone help me what the hell is happening here, I'm getting frustrated I keep draining the toner by testing out every setting change at this point...

Comment: I'm ready to roll back the update at this point, but I'm not even sure that's the problem...

Comment: I am having a similar issue, what model computer & OS are you using?

Comment: MSI GL Series, with Win 10 Home